# How to lock or revoke permission for Postgres user for temporarily

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

Can you please tell me how to lock a user in Postgres for temporarily. I have tried different commands but nothing seems to work.

1. REVOKE connect from john.
2. alter user john ACCOUNT lock;

please help me.
my ph_hba conf file

```
# IPv4 local & remote connections:

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             john             0.0.0.0/0               reject

# IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             john             0.0.0.0/0               reject
```

Answer (score 0):

`REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE` won't have an effect because `CONNECT` is granted to `PUBLIC` by default. You'd first have to `REVOKE CONNECT` on the database `FROM PUBLIC` and grant it to the users that need it.

There is no way to lock a user, but you can `ALTER ROLE ... VALID UNTIL 'yesterday'` to make the password expire.

The easiest way is typically to add a `reject` entry to `pg_hba.conf`.
Make sure, however, that you add the `reject` entry *above* the original entry that allows the user in.

Comment: Hi Thanks.I have the added the entry like this in pg_hba.conf but the user is still able to connect. can you please suggest.                                                                          host    all             john            0.0.0.0/0               reject

Comment: Did you add it at the top and run `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`?

Comment: Laurenz Albe .yeah i have restarted the postgres database also.my entries are,  


# IPv4 local           
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             john             0.0.0.0/0               reject
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             john             0.0.0.0/0               reject

Comment: Maybe it is a different database server? You should add more details to your question, like your `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: I have tried alter role also.This is also not working. ALTER ROLE JOHN with VALID UNTIL 'May 4 12:00:00 2015 +1';

Comment: You have to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53872610/edit) and add the information there. It is not readable in a comment.

Comment: Laurenz Albe .the question is edited..please check once.

Comment: You didn't add the `reject` entries on top like I said.

Comment: The entry is good, but **it has to be at the beginning of the file**. You might want to add another entry for IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Yeah..my purpose of this is i want to track this user executed how many queries per day.for example if it exceeds the query limit 100 then i want to disable the user for the day and enable him again for next day.what could be the best approach for this.can you please suggest something.

Comment: That's a totally different question, so you might ask it as such. There is no way to do that though, as far as I know.

Comment: I think that we can disable the password and enable him the very next day using alter role.can we do that .when i try with this ALTER ROLE john with VALID UNTIL '2016-06-22 19:10:25-07'; it is not working.